# How to create efficient time based triggering service?

Tags: algorithm, architecture, eventtrigger, system-design

We need to have a efficient time based triggers , so that we can set something in service and it can give us a callback when time comes. To elaborate we give trigger service callback the main application with some data (which is set while creating trigger) at some point of time. Currently one of the product is azure logic apps which does the same.

What is the efficient way to develop such servic.

Very basic I can think of is we can maintain min heap in ram (backed by some storage). which will keep the trigger (id) and its time at which main app is to be notified. by id we can store the the other trigger info in some storage. the thread to notify other services can be put on sleep till the next min time of the heap (because that is the earliest someone is to be notified). after thread complete its sleep it will comes up check the trigger and notify main app . and put back on sleep till next min value of heap

If the monitoring thread is already sleeping for X time , But if a new trigger comes up to get persisted
it will be persisted in min heap with Y as its trigger time.
Now if Y < X, monitoring thread need to be interrupted and again put on sleep considering Y time to awake.

What is the good algorithm, architecture for such service?